# Sort a list after incrementing one element

Tags: c++, sorting, stdlist

EDIT: I can't use the sort function.
I must do a program that has a list which is a ranking of organisms, each organism has its own ID and the ranking must be sorted decreasingly by number of sons and if two organisms have the same number of sons they are sorted increasingly by their ID.
I have made the following algorithm that goes after increasing the number of sons of one organism:

```
list<pair<int, int> >::iterator it = list.begin();
bool found = false;
int id = (id of the incremented organism)
int sons = (number of sons)
while(not found and it != list.end()) {
   if((*it).first == id) found = true;
   if(found and it != rkg.begin()) {
     --it;
     int prevsons = (*it).first;
     int previd = (*it).second;
     ++it;
     if(prevsons < sons or prevsons == sons and previd > id) {
         it = list.erase(it);
         while(((*it).second < sons or (*it).second == sons and (*it).first > id) and it != list.end) --it;
     list.insert(it, id);
     }
   }
   ++it;
}
```

but it doesn't work well as when i print the ranking after inserting some organisms it is sometimes badly sorted.
I would appreciate your help.
I can only use the following operations:

```
void list.clear();
void list.insert(iterator it, const T& x);
iterator list.erase(iterator it);
void splice(iterator it, list& l);
int size() const;
```

Sorry if i am expressing myself badly, my native language is not english.

Comment: Have you tried using the STL to sort the container? Or, is there a specific reason you wish to hand-craft your own sorting routine?

Comment: Why not just call [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort)? You can use your own sorting criteria if the default does not match your needs.

Comment: This program is an assignment and i must write the algorithm myself, i can't use the sort function, as i said i can only use the ones above.

Comment: Have you decided which sorting algorithm you want? Do you even need to sort it or do you always insert the objects at the correct place?

Comment: @flapedriza Then you should state clearly in the question that you have to write your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: @nwp Essentially, what i need to do is to put in the right place an organism after increasing its number of sons, not sort the entire list.

Comment: Take a look at [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). There is even an implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed it, i forgot to increment the iterator before inserting the element
adding:

```
if(it == list.begin() and not ((*it).second < sons or (*it).second == sons and (*it).first > id) or it != rkg.begin()) ++it;
```